# Where are aquatic elves defined?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, elf

Aquatic elves are mentioned under the *sahuagin* entry in the *Monster Manual*, and also in *Ghosts of Saltmarsh*, but I don't see them defined anywhere. Is there a stat block or other description of them anywhere beyond the *sahuagin* entry?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### *Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes* pages 62-63.

A description and set of racial traits for Sea Elves is found on pages 62 and 63 of *Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes*, as well as a brief description (including racial traits) on pages 163-164 of *Explorer’s Guide to Wildemount*.

This information can also be found [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/elf#SeaElf) at DNDBeyond, but requires that you purchase MToF or at least the Sea Elf subrace.

A basic monster [stat block for a sea elf](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/sea-elf) can be found on page 70 of the adventure *Storm King’s Thunder*, and *Ghost's of Saltmarsh* contains a statblock for a named sea elf, [Oceanus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/oceanus).